# I have a method compute(int months) but it does not iterate as I want it to be

Tags: java, loops, iteration

This is my method compute(), which takes in the number of months:

```
 public double compute(int months){
        double balance = employee.getSalary();
        double newBalance=0;
        double monthlyInterest = (bankName.getInterestRate())/12;
        double annualRaise = employee.getAnnualRaise();

if (months <=12){
      for (int i = 1; i <= months; i++){
        newBalance = (newBalance+balance)*(1+monthlyInterest);
      }
      return newBalance;
    }

    else{

      int cycle = months/12;

      while (cycle >0){
        for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++){
          newBalance = (newBalance+balance)*(1+monthlyInterest);
        }
        cycle--;

        months = months - 12; //remainder of months

        balance = balance*(1+annualRaise/100); //new starting salary

      }

      for (int k = 1; k <= months; k++){
        newBalance = (newBalance+balance)*(1+monthlyInterest);
      }
      return newBalance;
    }

  }
```

To give a context,

1. balance : is a fixed monthly pay an employee gets at the start of every month
2. monthly interest : is the interest rate that is computed on the balance in the employee's bank every month
3. annual raise : is the raise in employee's monthly pay at the start of a new year

An example of my input will be:

```
Bill Jobs 54000.0 0 0.012 13
```

where Bill Jobs is the employee with 54K as his balance, annual raise of 0% and 1.2% of annual interest rate from the bank, the duration of computation will be over 13 months. My desired output should be:

```
Bill Jobs: salary is 54K, annual raise is 0% has balance of 706933.71
```

where the balance of 706933.71 is computed when I call for the compute method, however I end up getting

```
Bill Jobs: salary is 54K, annual raise is 0% has balance of 705852.63
```

where his balance after 13 months is 705852.63 instead.

Comment: I have run your code but it seems that it is giving the correct results. Can you edit the question to include your inputs and how you called the method?

Comment: I can't see any bug in the part where `months <= 12`.  I think there's a bug towards the end of the `else` block, but it won't affect the case where `months = 2`.  I suggest you step through this with your debugger, to see exactly what's happening.

Comment: @Mark I have made the edit to include an example!

Comment: @Cheryl, I don't know why you are getting that input but when I run your code I got ```706933.7101622699```, which based from your question is correct. Try to use debugger and make sure you are passing the value of the inputs correctly

Answer (score 0):

Refer below basic calculation for salary added with interest rate of 1.5% for every month. You can modify this according to your requirement.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Salary {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    double salary = 24000;
    double interest = 1.5;
    double total = 0;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the month = ");
    int month = sc.nextInt();
    if(month != 0 && month  < 13){
        for(int i=1; i <= month; i++){
            salary += total;
            total = (salary + (salary * (interest/100)))  ;
        }
        System.out.println("salary with interest "+total);
    }else{
        System.out.println("Enter the month from 1-12");
    }


   }

}
```

Comment: I don't think there's anything in here that Cheryl doesn't already know how to do.  Her requirement is considerably more complicated than this.